# Show tags between question title and body

Tags: feature-request, tags, design

That would help some of us who don't always see them to answer questions more accurately.

Comment: "That would help *some of us*..." - Ok, well that would also annoy *some of us*.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how this helps. You (generally) see them before you click on the question. If you didn't, then the question was interesting enough in its own right, and you can look at the tags when you're done reading it.

**Besides, they also appear on the top right of the screen *next* to the question.**

[image]

Comment: Point taken.  I suppose my limited experience has not yes trained my eyes.  But that speaks to UX, not repeated use, right? For longer questions, without going out my way to read outside the question, I don't know if someone is asking about SQL Server or MySql or Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a userscript for you that does this.

[Click to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/MoveTags.user.js)---[Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/MoveTags.user.js)

(Requires FireFox with Greasemonkey *or* Chrome)